# Excel keeps rounding numbers into full numbers (e.g. shows 5.00) instead of displaying decimals

Tags: excel

I have been trying to fix this for over an hour now, trying every possible answer I have read on every forum and site when Googling.

I have a series of numbers that I want to multiply by 0.15 (15 cents). However, instead of showing the actual result (33 * 0.15 = 4.95) it shows a ful number.

A full number with decimals (that is, 5.00) but a full number. As you see, it is not an issue of increasing or decreasing decimals, format, etc.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ON the "Home table" click on the "decrease" or "increase" decimal (to the right of what appears on your tab-bar as "Numero"

[image]

If that doesnt work, if you look at the actual contact of the cell is there a formula in it (rather than numbers? i.e. something like:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,-2)
=ROUNDUP(A1,-2)
=ROUND(A1,-2)
```

They also force rounding of numbers.

And finally the only other option I can think of is looking at the "cell format", but from what it appears you already have it on "Money"...

Just incase, double check that it's not a form of finance that "rounds off" figures. As That happens too!

Comment: Adrian, thanks, but it is not that. It just keeps adding zeros, but does not show the actual number with decimals. That is, I want it to say/display 4.75 (33 * 0.15) not 5.00 or 5.0000.

Comment: What happens if you try: =4.75 (33 * 0.15) not 5.00 or 5.0000 <-- with the equals and to rule things out, try =4.75 (33.00 * 0.15) not 5.00 or 5.0000 <-- with .00 after (33... incase excel is using that to "infer" the decimal value (it might take the number with the last digits as a reference to use for calculations.

Comment: In a new sheet or a new workbook type 4.75 in a cell. If that value shows as 4.75 then copy and paste special format on your target cell.